How do i replace the default Ender Dragon with my custom one?
Pretty straightforward, i just started using NMS and i wanna make a custom Ender Dragon with some attributes changed (faster, bigger, etc etc) to replace the default one. I'm using NMS on 1.20.4 but i'm not sure how to control that the Dragon that spawns is my custom one? i'm using Mojang mappings so that may be the reason i don't find how to do it but would appreciate some help!
Looked for some method like "onChunkLoad" or similar, but i think Mojang mappings do not use that name

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You can just cancel the default one spawning and slap in your own one. CreatureSpawnEvent would be the spigot event.
In NMS this should work
@Override
public void spawnEntity(org.bukkit.World world, EntityTypes entityTypes, Location location, CreatureSpawnEvent.SpawnReason spawnReason) {
    // Check if the entity being spawned is an Ender Dragon
    if (entityTypes == EntityTypes.ENDER_DRAGON) {
        // Handle Ender Dragon spawning
        return;
    }

    // Call the super method to spawn the entity
    super.spawnEntity(world, entityTypes, location, spawnReason);
}

